# Fstab bind network shared folder: mount error(6): No such device or address

Tags: mount, fstab, cifs, nas

trying to bind a shared folder located on my NAS in fstab using

```
//192.168.178.150/array1    /home/myUser/test cifs username=myUser,passwd=**** 0 0
```

I get the following error

```
Retrying with upper case share name
mount error(6): No such device or address
Refer to the mount.cifs(8) manual page (e.g. man mount.cifs)
```

I dont know what to make of this. Accessing the folder manually using the file manager is no problem and I would not even need to give my credentials.

Comment: Can you connect to the CIFS share using a regular CIFS client (e. g. Nautilus) or with a manual invocation of `mount`?

Comment: I can connect using the file manager. However mounting the drive manually using `sudo mount //192.168.178.150/ /home/myUser/test` results in the same error I posted above. However now it requests a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying `smbclient -L //192.168.178.150` I found that the path was not correct. On the NAS its true that all shared folders are contained by some directory `array1` but the smb shared names are the subfolders directly. Therefore

```
//192.168.178.150/subfolder    /home/myUser/test cifs username=myUser,passwd=**** 0 0
```

did the job.